# force HasMany() to use an association table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

First question here, even if I have been browsing stack for years now.

I have a problem with Entity Framework and Migration, more precisely with mapping.
I'm well aware of all the questions regarding many-to-many, one-to-many, association table and stuff but I have not come accross a solution for this particular problem:

These are my POCO:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual long Id {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<B> B {get; set;}
}

public class B
{
    public virtual long Id {get; set;}

    // Not relevant stuff ...
}
```

I want to force mapping to give me an association table, something that may look like this:

```
-----------   -----------   -----------
| TABLE A |   | TABLE AB|   | TABLE B |
-----------   -----------   -----------
| ID      |   | FK_A_ID |   | ID      |
-----------   | FK_B_ID |   -----------
              -----------
```

My first reaction was to use this kind of mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
                .HasMany(x => x.B)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(x =>
                {
                    x.ToTable("AB");
                    x.MapLeftKey("Id");
                    x.MapRightKey("Id");
                });
```

Unfortunately, this does not give me the desired mapping in database, cause it is creating a foreign-key in table A referencing B.Id. Plus, I do not want to have a property on A within B class. For information, the destination database is SqlServer.

Is there a proper way to do this ?

Note: I'm not a native english speaker, forgive me if I made mistakes.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are trying to achieve that, but, it is possible.

The hypotesis that came in my mind is that you can't edit neither `A` or `B` but you wanted the many many relationship... so this is one solution:

Just create a class `AB` with both id of `A` and `B` then define the keys and the discriminator with decorators

```
class AB {
    virtual public A ALink {get; set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ALinkId {get; set;}

    virtual public B BLink {get; set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public it BLinkId {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: upvoted this cause, yes, your solution works, however, the whole point was not to hand code another class. Like in many-to-many association, where the association table is set for you, ensuring cascading delete and stuff.

Comment: This IS a Many to many relationship.
Entity framework will automatically generate the middleware table for you if you just create a list of A in B class.
There will be no need of configuring anything

Comment: As I can see there is no more answers to this topic, have you found a better solution? ORM task is to give some standards to semplify working with databases not doing work in your place...

Comment: Was away from internet so i couldn't mark this as the answer sooner. For the second part, I unfortunately do not agree with you. Sure the whole point ORM is to simplify data persistency for devs, but it's also a tool that enables you to interact further with the db (especially when we're talking of EF API, conventions, modelbuilder and stuff...).

Comment: I used to think the same, but reality is, we have to write a lot of code :)